# I want to save table in a cell of CSV but changing line automatically in case of large table

Tags: php, csv

![I want to save table in a cell of CSV but changing line automatically in case of large table
thanks in advance
code to write CSV`

> when I export csv of scraped data it messed up when table contains large number of rows or tr's  please help me out of this.
>   `

```
$fp = fopen('stream.csv', "w");
foreach ($output as $row) {
fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
fclose($df);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "messed up"..... what error do you get? How are you checking if it's "messed up"? How many rows are you talking about? What has a `tr` got to do with a csv file?

Comment: Please provide necessary information @Syed.

Comment: https://scontent-mxp.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/10646833_916032275108780_2186873217783143840_n.jpg?oh=c89370463ec52994597116c1758d5a60&oe=557FA48F

see this is screenshot of CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is really not clear enough but here is how I generate my CSV files. Good thing is that it also shows column names automatically.

```
$result = mysqli_query ($mysqliConn,"SELECT * FROM core ORDER BY start_datetime ASC");

$fields = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);

if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
$num_fields = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
$headers = array();

foreach ($fields as $field) {
                $headers[] = $field->name;
}

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="core.csv"');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    fputcsv($fp, $headers);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    }
    die;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already have done this ....
https://scontent-mxp.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/10646833_916032275108780_2186873217783143840_n.jpg?oh=c89370463ec52994597116c1758d5a60&oe=557FA48F

see this is screenshot of CSV

Comment: What is the point of using <td> i.e. HTML tags inside for a CSV file? Isn't that meant to be Comma Separated? so that Excel or other spreadsheet can open it correctly?

Comment: @SyedAmmadIqbal if this worked for you, can you accept it as your Answer?